# Entity Framework Code First Many to Many relationship(s) in single table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first

I've been lurking around for quite some time, so here's the first question ;)

I've been playing with Entity Framework 5.0 Code First and I want to do following:

I have two entities and I want every entity to have relation to Address entity in the following way:

- I have one **Address** entity which stores address values, it doesn't have relation to entities for which it has values, instead
- There's another entity **AddressBook** which has reference to **Address** entity and the coresponding entities (**Person**, **Company**, some others in the future)

Here's code:

```
public partial class Address : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int? PostalCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Person : BaseEntity 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

}

public partial class Company: BaseEntity 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

What will this do is create database schema with tables:

- Address
- AddressPerson (with composite primary key)

  - Address_ID
  - Person_ID
- AddressCompany

  - Address_ID
  - Company_ID
- People
- Companies

Here's what I want to do:

- Address
- AddressBook

  - Address_ID (PK)
  - Person_ID (FK)
  - Company_ID (FK)
- People
- Companies

What I want to do is have table like **AddressBook**:

```
public partial class AddressBook
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure how to define navigational properties in **Person** and **Company** class.

They should have  `ICollection<Address> Addresses` navigational property, because I want them to work just with collection of addresses without knowing about underlying **AddressBook**.

Is it possible to do this with `DbModelBuilder` or should I write code inside `getter` and `setter` of `ICollection<Address> Addresses` property and get addresses from **AddressBook**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a mapping in a way that Entity Framework would understand the `Addresses` collections in `Person` and `Company` as true navigation properties (which support eager and lazy loading and so on). For this you need indeed `AddressBooks` collections. You can add the `Addresses` as not mapped and readonly helper properties then:

```
public partial class Person : BaseEntity 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AddressBook> AddressBookEntries { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses
    {
        get { return AddressBookEntries.Select(ab => ab.Address); }
    }
}
```

(The same with `Company`.)

An alternative and in my opinion better approach would be to create a common base class for `Person` and `Company`, move the `Addresses` collection into that base class and have a single many-to-many relationship and single join table between this base class and `Address`:

```
public abstract class EntityWithAddresses : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public partial class Person : EntityWithAddresses 
{
}

public partial class Company : EntityWithAddresses 
{
}
```

`Address` has a navigation collection to the new base class:

```
public partial class Address : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int? PostalCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EntityWithAddresses> EntityWithAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help - I've come to conclusion that I should do something like in the first example. I've even coded part of the solution, but I didn't quite like it. I thought there should be better way.